# spring security run with spring boot embedded server getUserPrincipal is null

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

everyone. I would like to ask a question which has bothered me for several days.
When I use spring Security with Spring Boot embedded server. I want to get the current login user by **HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal()**. But the result is **null**.

```
@RequestMapping("/user/index")
public String userIndex(Principal principal, Authentication authentication, HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("principal " + principal.getName());
    System.out.println("authentication " + authentication.getName());

    Authentication authenticationx = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    System.out.println("SecurityContextHolder " + authenticationx.getName());
    System.out.println("request : " + request.getUserPrincipal());
    // can't get the user with the embedded server
    return "user/index";
}
```

**The Principal  and Authentication object** can be used to get the current User!!!, But the request object can not. The result is null.
The document of spring-security points out that the api of **request.getUserPrincipal()** can be used to get the user info.

[spring-security documents](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/)

Just before the header of 5.1.1.

When I replace the embedded JavaEE server with an **external Tomcat**, I can **use all of the above methods** to get the current login user.

Who can tell me why? Thank you every much!!!

Comment: I experienced the same thing.  Even though I could still see that the client cert was in the request.  I could see it using the following:

`request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate")`